# Is my cable or iGPU at fault here?

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, hdmi, gpu, cable

I have a 1440p 240Hz monitor and I would like to fully utility the refresh rate at the monitor native resolution.

I have a Ryzen 2500U CPU with Vega 8 iGPU integrated.

I have a bit older cable connecting the display and laptop and I would assume it's HDMI 1.4 which to my knowledge supports 1440p60Hz max (?)

P.S. I am running Debian 12 if that matters.

My goal is to also enable VRR if possible at 240Hz.

My xrandr output:

```
non-desktop: 0 
                range: (0, 1)
   2560x1440     59.95* 
   1920x1080    120.00   119.88    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

Comment: AMD don't seem to provide any spec for this that I can find - https://www.amd.com/en/products/specifications/embedded - but I'd be very surprised if a basic IGPU from more than 5 years ago could do better than 60Hz @1440p

Comment: @Tetsujin You might be right: https://www.amd.com/en/product/5311 AMD simply does not give any info regarding this...

Comment: tbh, even if it could manage that kind of frequency, it would probably glow in the dark, it would get that hot. Laptops already tend to be poor at pushing external display at 'gaming' spec.